# Find and replace functions without modifying parameters/variables

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following:

Replace references to the function "example()" with "example2()", ensuring that any parameters are not modified.

This needs to be run on all files ending with the extension ".sh".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/\<example(/example2(/' *.sh
```

`-i` will change the file in place. Omit it to get a preview of the changes.

`\<example(` will find occurrences of example and replace it with `example2(`.

Comment: Except functions in shell scripts usually don't utilize parentheses at the call site... Probably should be `s/\<example\>/example2/g`, except that will also change the word example anywhere else (e.g. in comments, text strings, etc.), which may not be desired. I'm not sure it's as simple as that...